# Is $\sinh(W_t+t)$ a submartingale, and the expected value

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have $X_t=\sinh (W_t+t)$. I am not sure how to show if this is a submartingale, and how to calculate its expectation.

I don't want to integrate this against the normal distribution to find the expectation. Does anyone have a short cut to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $0\leq s\leq t$, simple calculations give 
\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}(\sinh(W_t+t)\ |\ {\cal F}_s)
&=&{\mathbb{E}(\exp(W_t+t)\ |\ {\cal F}_s)-\mathbb{E}(\exp(-W_t-t)\ |\ {\cal F}_s)\over 2}\cr
&=&{\exp(W_s+t)-\exp(-W_s-t)\over 2}\exp((t-s)^2/2)\cr
&=&\sinh(W_s+t)\exp((t-s)^2/2).
\end{eqnarray*}

1. Setting $s=0$, we get the expectation  $\mathbb{E}(\sinh(W_t+t))=\sinh(t)\exp(t^2/2)$.
2. Also since $\sinh$ is an increasing function, we have 
   $$\mathbb{E}(\sinh(W_t+t)\ |\ {\cal F}_s)=\sinh(W_s+t)\ \exp((t-s)^2/2)\geq \sinh(W_s+s)$$
   which gives the submartingale property.